# How to Scroll in div inside another div in html .in this case how can i scroll to div 2

Tags: html, css, scroll, html5-canvas

> > I already tried href with ID to navigate but its not working to navigate inside the specific div
> > how can i navigate to id 2 from href
> > `<div id="main"> <div id="1"></div> <div id="2"></div> </div>`

Comment: Nice first post! It would help others to solve the problem if you could add an example of what you have tried. So instead of saying *"I already tried href with ID... "*, you could say *"I already tried the following `<div id="main" href="#2>`"*.

Answer (score 1):

If you write into the div a paragraph you can `href` on that and it will take you inside the div.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#nav">To 2</a>
        <div id="main"> 
            <div id="1"></div> 
            <div id="2">
                <p id="nav"></p>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```